# How can I format multiple data in a single HTTP POST request in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I am struggling with this HTTP POST in the requests library in Python. I cannot format the following HTTP POST request for a Python script:

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACauth_code/Messages.json \
  --data-urlencode "To=whatsapp:+1111111111” \
  --data-urlencode "From=whatsapp:+111111111” \
  --data-urlencode "Body=Thanks for contacting me on WhatsApp! Here is a picture of an owl." \
  --data-urlencode "MediaUrl=https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png" \
  -u 'ACauth_code:auth_token
```

Could someone help me format this for the Python requests library?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC_user/Messages.json"
params = {
    "To" : "whatsapp:+111111111",
    "From" : "whatsapp:+11111111",
    "Body" : "Thanks for contacting me on WhatsApp! Here is a picture of an owl.",
    "MediaUrl" : "https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png"
    }
res = requests.post(url, params, auth=('AC_user','password/token'))
res = res.json()
```